# I want my website max-height would be equal as window height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my website max-height would be equal as window height.No matter how many content inside it.Specially this my site link http://styleweb.comyr.com/test .There are four images in right div which I need to scroll to view all images.I want those images also resized when I resize the window height with perfect portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all four images shall be below each other, you can use

```
img { max-height: 25vh; }
```

`vh` is a unit relative to the viewport height, `100vh` is full height, `25vh` is a quarter of that, thus 4 images will neatly stack.